# Casting class variables in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, casting

I need to cast a variable where I store an object depending on some conditions.
I have this var:

```
class MyClass {
  public referrers: SelectItemGroup[];
}
```

This type is an object and you have to provide a label, items and optionally a value. The trouble comes when depending on some stuff I need to add only a few elements to this array and they don't have items so I need to cast `this.referrers` from `SelectItemGroup[]` to `SelectItem[]` and I am not really sure of how to do this.

I tried `this.referrers = <SelectItem[]>this.referrers;` which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: `SelectItem` and `SelectItemGroup` are classes ?

Comment: No, they are interfaces

Comment: So `referrers` needs to contain both `SelectItem` and `SelectItemGroup` ? Why not just type `referrers` as a union type : `referrers: (SelectItem | SelectItemGroup)[]` ?

Comment: Simply cuz I didn't know that I could do that. Thank you so much it solved my question and also made me learn something very useful. Thanks a lot

Comment: Added a bit more detail in an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'casting' operator you used is called a type assertion in typescript, the reason it's called an assertion is that as opposed to a casting from other languages it has no runtime behavior (no conversion is done, no runtime error occurs if the value is incompatible with the asserted type). Type assertions are useful when you have more information then the compiler about the type of value and want to let the compiler know about it.

If this case using this assertion would let you access operations of the `referrers` array typed with `SelectItem`. So this code should work:

```
class MyClass {
    public referrers: SelectItemGroup[];
    method() {
        let s: SelectItem = this.createSelectItem();
        (<SelectItem[]>this.referrers).push(s)
    }
}
```

Now the array will contain both `SelectItemGroup` and `SelectItem` but we should let the compiler know about this. Typescript supports a feature called [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) which allows us to specify a type is either one of two other types (ex: `A | B`) so we could type the `referrers` as an array of such a union type, making the assertion unecessary:

```
class MyClass {
    public referrers: (SelectItemGroup | SelectItem)[];
    method() {
        let s: SelectItem = this.createSelectItem();
        this.referrers.push(s);
    }
}
```

When accessing members of `referrers` we now have a different problem, since an item can be either `SelectItemGroup` or `SelectItem` the compiler will only let us access common members:

```
interface SelectItemGroup{
    name: string;
    children: SelectItem[]
}
interface SelectItem{
    name: string;
    value: string;
}
class MyClass {
    public referrers: (SelectItemGroup | SelectItem)[];
    method() {
        this.referrers[0].name // valid it's common
        this.referrers[0].value // invalid belongs only to SelectItem
        this.referrers[0].children // invalid belongs only to SelectItemGroup
    }
}
```

To narrow the type of the element to one or the other type we need to use a type guard. Typescript offers several types of type guards and you can read more about them [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) as well. The most convenient in this case would be an `in` type guard which will determine the type based on the existence of a particular field:

```
class MyClass {
    public referrers: (SelectItemGroup | SelectItem)[];
    method() {
        // type-guards will not work directly on the array we need to put the value in a local variable 
        let item = this.referrers[0] // item is SelectItemGroup | SelectItem so only name is accessible 
        if('children' in item) {
            item.children // valid item is SelectItemGroup
        }else{
            item.value // valid item is SelectItem by exclusion 
        }
    }
}
```